# What is the difference between `np.histogram` and `plt.hist`? Why don't these commands plot the same graphics?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, matplotlib

UPDATE: Sorry again, the code was updated due to correct comments. And there is still some problem with graphics - one hist is shifted to another.

UPDATE: I'm sorry, these hists have different number of bins. And even at this point setting '5' as number of bins in `plt.hist` doesn't help

The code below computes two histograms on the same datasource.
And plotting these histograms shows that they don't coincide. 
A mark for `np.hist` : it returns a tuple of two arrays - values of bins including edge bins and a number of counts. So I thought that it could be reasonable to center values of bin edge locations.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
s = [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,5,5,5,6,7,7,7,7,7,7,7]

xmin = 1
xmax = 7
step = 1.
print 'nbins=',(xmax-xmin)/step
print np.linspace(xmin, xmax, (xmax-xmin)/step)
h1 = np.histogram(s, bins=np.linspace(xmin, xmax, (xmax-xmin)/step))
print h1
def calc_centers_of_bins(x):
    return  list(x[i]+(x[i]-x[i+1])/2.0 for i in xrange(len(x)-1))

x = h1[1].tolist()
print x
y = h1[0].tolist()


plt.bar(calc_centers_of_bins(x),y, width=(x[-1]-x[0])/(len(y)), color='red', alpha=0.5)
plt.hist(s, bins=5,alpha=0.5)
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: You're using different bins.  `np.linspace(xmin, xmax, (xmax-xmin)/step)` has 5 bins, but you've told `plt.hist` to use 6.

Comment: @askewchan You're right, thank you. But even at this occasion plots don't coincide...

Comment: It's a plotting issue, `plt.bar` expects to see the left edge, not the center.  See my edited answer.

Comment: By the way, you say "a mark for `np.histogram`" is that it returns the values and bins ... so does `plt.hist`, it returns the values, bin edges, and the plotting info, so you can do: `y, x, _ = plt.hist()` (where the `_` is just a throwaway variable).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're using different bins in the two cases. In your case, `np.linspace(xmin, xmax, (xmax-xmin)/step)` has 5 bins, but you've told `plt.hist` to use 6 bins.

You can see this by looking at the output of each:

```
h1 = np.histogram(s, bins=np.linspace(xmin, xmax, (xmax-xmin)/step))
h_plt = plt.hist(s, bins=6,alpha=0.5)
```

Then:

```
>>> h1[1]
array([ 1. ,  2.2,  3.4,  4.6,  5.8,  7. ])
>>> h_plt[1]
array([ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.,  7.])
```

I would use:

```
y, x = np.histogram(s, bins=np.linspace(xmin, xmax, (xmax-xmin)/step))
nbins = y.size
# ...
plt.hist(s, bins=nbins, alpha=0.5)
```

Then your histograms match, but your plot still won't because you've plotted the output of your `np.histogram` at the centers of the bins, but `plt.bar` expects an array of the left edges:

> `plt.bar(left, height, width=0.8, bottom=None, hold=None, **kwargs)`
>
> Parameters
>   `----------`
>   `left` : sequence of scalars
>       the `x` coordinates of the left sides of the bars
>
> `height` : sequence of scalars
>       the heights of the bars

What you want is:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
s = [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,5,5,5,6,7,7,7,7,7,7,7]

xmin = 1
xmax = 7
step = 1
y, x = np.histogram(s, bins=np.linspace(xmin, xmax, (xmax-xmin)/step))

nbins = y.size

plt.bar(x[:-1], y, width=x[1]-x[0], color='red', alpha=0.5)
plt.hist(s, bins=nbins, alpha=0.5)
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

[image: two hists]

Comment: Now I see that I had wrong way with centering bins by their edges. You just skip the last value and it is more clear and simple, thanks a lot!

Comment: Your'e welcome!  I didn't mention in the answer, but to find the centers of the bins, if `x` is a numpy array (which it is by default if you don't call `x.tolist()`, then you can say: `centers = (x[1:] - x[:-1])/2.`

Comment: It should say +:  centers = (x[1:] + x[:-1])/2.